# Table View setEditing for selected cell at indexPath

Tags: objective-c, xcode, uitableview, setediting

I want to enable editing for a single cell in a Table View at the selected index of a long press event, everything works except it enables editing for the entire table. How can I enable editing only on the cell that is selected?

```
-(void)handleLongPress:(UILongPressGestureRecognizer *)gestureRecognizer {

    CGPoint p = [gestureRecognizer locationInView:self.savedPropertyTableView];

    NSIndexPath *indexPath = [self.savedPropertyTableView indexPathForRowAtPoint:p];
            if (indexPath == nil) {
            [self setEditing:YES animated:YES];
            NSLog(@"long press on table view but not on a row");
        }

        else {
            [self setEditing:YES animated:YES];
            NSLog(@"long press on table view at row %d", indexPath.row);
        } 
    }
```

Comment: In the above code you set editing to YES in both case???

Comment: I am interested in it editing a single cell if they select a cell, if no cells are selected editing for all cells will be enabled.

Comment: Instead of whole table make that single cell editable..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not a exact solution but same result, i have created a swipe gesture instead and that works like i was hoping (delete a single cell)

In the Table View Cell:

```
UISwipeGestureRecognizer *sgdr = [[UISwipeGestureRecognizer alloc] initWithTarget:self action:@selector(handleSlideRight:)];
[sgdr setDirection:UISwipeGestureRecognizerDirectionRight];
[self.savedPropertyTableView addGestureRecognizer:lpgr];
```

Then created method:

```
-(void)handleSlideRight:(UISwipeGestureRecognizer *)gestureRecognizer {
    CGPoint p = [gestureRecognizer locationInView:self.savedPropertyTableView];

    NSIndexPath *indexPath = [self.savedPropertyTableView indexPathForRowAtPoint:p];
    if (indexPath == nil)
    {
        [self setEditing:YES animated:YES];
        NSLog(@"slide on table view but not on a row");
    }

    else
    {
        [self setEditing:YES animated:YES];
        NSLog(@"slide on table view at row %d", indexPath.row);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Instead of whole table make that single cell editable :

```
UITableViewCell *newCell = [yourTable cellForRowAtIndexPath:indexPath];

[newCell setEditing:YES animated:YES];
```

Comment: Unfortunately this doesnt work, maybe something to do with the red `-` that comes up not letting it be on a single cell. Either way swipe works exactly as intended. Thanks for the help